# Build error while referring .scss with open iconic package

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

I am working with bootstrap 4 scss with open-iconic package. when I refer import '~open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.scss from style.scss, I am facing below error. any suggestions please.

[image]

Comment: The files are not where node is expecting them... have a look at the paths entered in the sass files and update it to point to the right files. If you need more info, we need to know where where the eot and sass files are, and the path you entered in the sass files.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
$icon-font-path: "~open-iconic/font/fonts/";
@import "~open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap";
```

I had a similar problem trying to work with Angular 5. It seems webpack isn't resolving the relative path in iconic's file correctly. It's trying to resolve it relative to the app folder.

Comment: At least in open-iconic 1.1.1 the var is `$iconic-font-path`.